# randomForest doesnt recognize 3 classes

Tags: r, random-forest

I am new to r. I am trying to find out the variable importance using random forest in r. I am using the package `randomForest()`. In the below code, `train` is the training set and the `trainy` is the target variable. The target variable signifies three classes which I have coded as 0,1,2 respectively.

```
require(randomForest)
train<-read.csv('TrData.csv',header=FALSE,sep=",")
trainy<-read.csv('TrData_y.csv',header=FALSE,sep=",")
trainy <- data.frame(lapply(trainy, factor))
set.seed(415)
fit <- randomForest(train,trainy,importance=TRUE, ntree=1000,proximity=TRUE)
```

Now when I run this code and display the `summary(fit)` the result is as follows.

```
 summary(fit)
                   Length  Class  Mode     
 call                  4 -none- call     
 type                  1 -none- character
 predicted             0 -none- NULL     
 err.rate              0 -none- NULL     
 confusion             0 -none- NULL     
 votes              5580 matrix numeric  
 oob.times          2790 -none- numeric  
 classes               2 -none- character
 importance         4100 -none- numeric  
 importanceSD       3075 -none- numeric  
 localImportance       0 -none- NULL     
 proximity       7784100 -none- numeric  
 ntree                 1 -none- numeric  
 mtry                  1 -none- numeric  
 forest                0 -none- NULL     
 y                     0 -none- NULL     
 test                  0 -none- NULL     
 inbag                 0 -none- NULL     
 > sapply(trainy,is.factor)
   V1 
   TRUE
```

`classes` shows 2 but there are 3 classes and the `ntree` shows `1`  but in the parameters I had specified 1000 trees to build the forest. I don't know what I am doing wrong in the code. When I serached about this I found this other question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34363/randomforest-chooses-regression-instead-of-classification. So I chceked to see whether the target variable is recognized as factor and there is no problem. Also I used the `importance` to extract the variable importance

```
featimpt=importance(fit)
write.csv(file="featureimportance_R.csv",x=featimpt)
```

This gives a output as follows[image]

Variable importance with respect to only 2 classes are available.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong with the code here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're just misinterpreting the output, nothing looks particularly wrong to me with your setup.  How many predictors are in your model?

Comment: What does `class(trainy)` show you?  If you want to run random forests in classification mode, the response needs to be a factor.

Comment: Does predictors mean variables ? there are 1024 variables and 2800 samples. And 'response' means the target variable i.e trainy right ? Yes it is a factor. As I have shown above I checked with `sapply(trainy,is.factor)` and it returned true. The `class(trainy)` shows `data.frame`. I dont know if this is right or wrong.

Comment: Maybe I am misinterpeting but what I find most odd about the result is that classifier says there are only 2 classes. randomForest() is supposed to be a supervised learning classifier and the `trainy` is supposed to fit the classifier to identify 3 classes. I am unable to understand this question.

Comment: What you're asking for makes no sense.  After building your model, you want to know how imporant each of the `1024` predictor variables are, _not_ the value of the response.  The value of the response matters while building the model, but not so much when you want to assess how good the model is.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I found the answer. The response is supposed to be a vector and I was feeding a `data.frame`. when I subsetted `trainy` as `trainy[,1], the problem got solved. I got the variable importances with respect to three classes as I should.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, glad you were able to sort it out.  Anyway, the importance output is showing which predictors had the greatest impact on the model.  In my experience, typically there are say 3-5 predictors which dominate the model, with important rapidly trailing off after that.